# How come only some audio will play through my headset and other sounds will only play through my speakers?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, microphone

I just built a new computer, msi x99a motherboard. On-board audio. Windows 10.

Well I have a headset. Headphones+ a microphone.

On my old PC all I had to do was plug the mic in and the headphones in and it would work. It would play audio through my headphones.

Well on this new PC, some audio plays through my headphones but other audio plays through my speakers.

When I take a Skype call, the audio will play through my speakers. When I open sounds and devices, and I click test device, it will play the test sound through my headphones.

I right clicked on my device and chose "use as default communication device" but its still playing through my speakers, not my headphones.

I restarted my PC. I uninstalled drivers. 
I updated.

Why wont this work? All I want is for all of my audio (games and voice chat) to go through my headphones not my speakers. It used to be as simple as clicking "set as default device" and it would work. Now it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the game sound outputs but in Skype you can set which speaker has to provide the audio output, You can change the setting in Options > Preferences and then select Audio/Video Here you can change your audio output settings. For more details use this link " https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA348/solving-your-speaker-or-headphones-issues-windows-desktop "